# Chrome getSelection not working if called from context menu

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a Chrome extension but I don't seem to be able to go past the first few lines.
The problem is that when I click on the context menu it fails to grab the selection from the document. It works fine obviously when I use it as a simple script included in an HTML page.

Here's the code:

```
var id = chrome.contextMenus.create({
    "title" : "Search",
    "contexts" : ["selection"],
    "onclick" : openUrl
});

function openUrl() {
    var sel = window.getSelection().toString().trim()
    alert(sel)
}
```

This code returns an empty alert box.

I have a script that on mouseup grabs the word that the user has selected and searches for this word on a dictionary. This script works fine I just need to execute it when the user clicks "Search" in the context menu.
So what I'm looking for is:
1) User selects a word from the document
2) Right clicks on it and clicks on the context menu
3) The script containing all instruction to be executed on that click.

I looked around before asking this question but I couldn't find anything probably because I'm pretty new to this awesome site. Please feel free to redirect me to other similiar question if I missed any. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function openUrl(info, tab) {
     alert(info.selectionText);
}
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! Could you please explain what are those info and tab parameters? Even a link to somewhere else will do. Thanks again!

Comment: [contextMenus](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/contextMenus.html#types) usually i even don't watch at specification - just make callback function in such way: function(e,r,t,y){console.log(e,r,t,y);} if there is some aruments in callback function I will see them, and chose what I need